# createRecord not defined error (Firebase + Ember.js)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction and help me fix this error I'm getting when I attempt to add a user with my Ember.js model after created a user with Firebases createUser method.

To be more specific here is the error I'm getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRecord' of undefined

```
App.SignUpController = Ember.Controller.extend({
needs: ['sign-in'],
needs: ['application'],
userSignedIn: false,


actions: {
    signMeUp: function() {
        var state = false;
        var controllerContext = this;
        // Create firebase user
        ref.createUser({
                email    : this.get('email'),
                password : this.get('password'),
            }, function(error, user) {
                if (error === null) {
                    console.log('User created with id', user.uid);
                    state = true;
                    controllerContext.set('userSignedIn', state);
                    console.log("State from sign-up page: "+ state);

                    console.log("Testing user.uid inside: "+user.uid);
                    var fbid = user.id;
                    controllerContext.set('user id', user.uid);

                    var newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', {
                          id: fbid,
                          email: this.get('email'),
                          password: this.get('password'),
                    });
                    newUser.save();
            } else {
                    console.log("Error creating account:", error);
            }
        }); // End createUser

        this.transitionToRoute('letters');
    }
}
 });
```

UPDATE: Here is a (very hacky) solution I came up with after a day of JS plumbing.

```
App.SignUpController = Ember.Controller.extend({
needs: ['sign-in'],
needs: ['application'],
userSignedIn: false,
thisUserID: '',

actions: {
    signMeUp: function() {
        var state = false;
        var controllerContext = this;
        // Create firebase user
        function authWithPassCallback(userObj, user){
            console.log("authWithPassCallback user.uid is: "+user.uid);
            return user.uid

        }

        function createUserAndLogin(userObj, callback) {  
           ref.createUser(userObj, function(error, user) {
              if (error === null) {
                console.log("User created successfully");
                controllerContext.set('thisUserID', user.uid);
                return callback(userObj, user);

              } else {
                console.log("Error creating user:", error);
              }  
            }); 


        }

        var userAndPass = { 
            email: this.get('email'),
            password: this.get('password')}

        var fbPayload = createUserAndLogin(userAndPass, authWithPassCallback);

        setTimeout(function () { 
            console.log("FB load: "+ controllerContext.get('thisUserID'));
            var newUser = controllerContext.store.createRecord('user', {
                              id: controllerContext.get('thisUserID'),
                              email: controllerContext.get("email"),
                              password: controllerContext.get("password"),
            });
            newUser.save();
            controllerContext.transitionToRoute('letters');
       }, 1000);
        console.log(controllerContext.get('thisUserID'));

    }
}
});
```

Comment: what's the error? which line?

Comment: @andrusieczko var newUser = this.store.createRecord('user',{...}); gives the error of createRecord not defined in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably just lost the context here. `this` doesn't refer to the `controller`, you're in the error function.

There are two ways of fixing that. First is to bind the function to the controller's `this`:

```
ref.createUser({
  // ...
}, function(error, user) {
  var newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', {/*...*/});
  // ...
}.bind(this));
```

or to reuse the `controllerContext` variable:

```
ref.createUser({
  // ...
}, function(error, user) {
  // ...
  var newUser = controllerContext.store.createRecord('user', {/*...*/});
});
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Lack of sleep really does things to ya. I'll give that a shot @andrusieczko. Thank you!

Comment: sometimes the easiest things are the hardest to spot ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the error is occurring at `newUser = this.store.createRecord` - at this point in your code `this` is no longer referring to the controller. You will need to use `controllerContext.store.createRecord`.

Comment: controllerContext.store.createRecord gives no error; however, the strange part is that the record does not get stored. I'm assuming this is a Firebase issue.

Comment: where is `ref` defined? How are you instantiating `Firebase`?

Comment: ref is defined at the top of my 'application.js' controller: var ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com");